# java code compilation heritage extends

Tags: java, access-modifiers

This code has a compilation problem. How do I get `a.f()`?

```
class A {
    int i = 1;

    int f() {
        return i;
    }

    static char g() {
        return 'A';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int i = 2;

    int f() {
        return -i;
    }

    static char g() {
        return 'B';
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.i);
        System.out.println(b.f());
        System.out.println(b.g());
        System.out.println(B.g());
        A a = b;
        System.out.println(a.i);
        System.out.println(a.f());
        System.out.println(a.g());
        System.out.println(A.g());
    }
}
```

and this is the result

```
2
-2
B
B
1
-2
A
A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding is just for instance methods, not for variables. So, when you get the variable i from instance of the class A, you get the value from this Class. The same thing with the instance of class B.

But you can reinitialize the value of i in constructor, for example:

```
class B extends A {

public B() {
    i=2;
}

int f() {
    return -i;
}

static char g() {
    return 'B';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've not specified any access modifiers for your class members, so it has default or package level access only and is not available to sub classes

```
Modifier    Class Package Subclass World
public      Y     Y       Y        Y 
protected   Y     Y       Y        N 
no modifier Y     Y       N        N 
private     Y     N       N        N
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more details

If you change the signature of `f()` to `protected int f()` then it should work

Of course you have the same issue with the other members of the class so it's up to you how you control this